# What does "jq" stand for?

Tags: jq

Question title is quite explicit already.

After using it for *a while* now, I figured it's weird not knowing what the name of one of my favourite tools actually stands for.
Checking the official website and GitHub didn't help much.
Although I assume it's "JSON Query" or something alike, it'd be nice to know; but opening an issue feels a bit overkill...

Comment: @unherz I believe both the title and `jq` tag make it pretty explicit that this is _*not*_ about _jQuery_.

Comment: If it isn't stated in the official documentation, you'll have to ask the author of the utility.

Answer (score 7):

jq (as in [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)) is a "JSON query language" and might perhaps therefore have been called "JQL" by analogy with "SQL", but jq is shorter :-)

Also note that jq is not only a JSON query language, but completely subsumes JSON: any valid JSON expression is a valid jq expression.

Furthermore, many valid jq expressions that are not valid JSON expressions are nevertheless structurally like JSON, e.g. `{a: 1}` and `{"a": .}`.

Comment: I can't seem to find an official answer to this, and followed @Amy 's advice to contact the project's author.
Will mark your answer as the right one should he answer my mail.  
This definitely makes sense and was pretty much what I had in mind =)

Comment: Would mark this as correct answer if the question wasn't locked.  
"JSON Query" does match, although 'jq' doesn't specifically "mean" anything. 
 
Asked the utility's author, which provided this interesting bit of trivia:  
"Honestly, the name was chosen to be short and easy to type on qwerty, not to have any particular meaning."